# Chrome: find out what request is sent when click a button on the web

Tags: google-chrome, web

I could open "developer tools -> Network -> XHR" to find all request made on the current page, but what I want to figure out now is that, there is a button "Search", when I type something in the textbox and click "Search" button, a new tab is opened in Chrome, and that means the "developer tools" cannot show what request has been made when I click the "Search" button.

Is there any way to find out the request initiated by the "Search" button?

Comment: Could you give me an example to test?

Answer (score 10):

In the Network tab, there is a `Preserve log` checkbox, which persists the requests between reloads and page navigation. Click on `XHR` to filter the requests. You can view the request headers on the right-side panel after clicking on the item in the list

[image: Preserve log]