# Any way to view old ajax requests in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome

Is there anyway to view old XHR calls in chrome?  I made an ajax form submission 2 hours ago but the form data wasn't saved to the database.  Is there a way i can see the form data that was submitted via ajax in the browsers history.    I've checked the "network" tab in developer tools but the it is empty.  How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't closed the tab in which you posted the form data, you could try [this solution.](https://superuser.com/a/781862/253195) to retrieve the data from the process dump.

More generally, if you are debugging XHR, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37044265/1814840) I wrote about preserving the request logs between reloads and navigation in the Network tab.